# Write, Read and Sort List of Lists in python

Tags: python, list, sorting, save

i have player_list. i want to save like in a file like this.

```
> John, 10
> Raymond, 20
> Oscar, 15

player_list = [['John', 10], ['Raymond', 20], ['Oscar', 15]]
# player_list.append(['Micheal',9])
# print(player_list)
with open('score_test.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in player_list:
        f.write("{},{} \n".format(item[0], item[1]))
```

then read that 'score_test.txt' file and print like this
[['John', 10], ['Raymond', 20], ['Oscar', 15]]

```
with open('score_test.txt', 'r') as file:
    words = file.read().splitlines()
print(words)
```

then append ['Micheal',19] and become [['John', 10], ['Raymond', 20], ['Oscar', 15],['Micheal',19]]

then sorted it's mark 
[['Raymond', 20],['Micheal',19],['Oscar', 15],['John', 10]] then write to a file again. thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: So you want help with sort or reading file or writing file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
player_list = [['John', 10], ['Raymond', 20], ['Oscar', 15]]

with open('a.txt','w') as filee:
  for val in player_list:
    filee.write(f'{val[0]}, {val[1]}')
    filee.write('\n')

d = []

with open('a.txt', 'r') as file:
    words = file.read().splitlines()
    for word in words:
      temp = word.split(',')
      temp[1] = int(temp[1].strip())
      d.append(temp)

d.append(['Micheal',19])

player_list = sorted(d, key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)

with open('a.txt','w') as filee:
  for val in player_list:
    filee.write(f'{val[0]}, {val[1]}')
    filee.write('\n')
```

I think this might help you.